# In Powershell how can I access an XML element containing only text?

Tags: xml, powershell

In Windows Powershell, I have an XML document which contains an element whose content is text. When an element contains another element, like $x.a in the example below, it is exposed as an element, while the text only child ($x.a.b) is exposed as a string.

```
PS C:\> $x = [xml]"<a><b>Some Text</b></a>
PS C:\> $x.a -is [Xml.XmlElement]
True
PS C:\> $x.a.b -is [Xml.XmlElement]
False
PS C:\> $x.a.b -is [string]
True
```

I can understand why this is convenient, but I would like to access b as an XmlElement. Is this possible, and if so, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `GetElementByTagName` method. Ex:

```
$x.a.GetElementsByTagName("b")

#text
-----
Some Text

$x.a.GetElementsByTagName("b").gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    XmlElementList                           System.Xml.XmlNodeList


$x.a.GetElementsByTagName("b")[0].gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    XmlElement                               System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode
```

Or using xpath if you prefer:

```
$x.a.SelectSingleNode("b")

#text
-----
Some Text

$x.a.SelectSingleNode("b").gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    XmlElement                               System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode
```

Comment: I was looking for a different way to access b, but this works. If the only way is to use XmlDocument methods, then perhaps `$x.a.selectSingleNode("b")` is cleaner/terser. Still - a good answer.

Comment: my answer includes `selectsinglenode`. I updated it 2 mins after that first answer =)